# Как в Windows заблокировать список закрытых соединений через отладку?

Tags: c, windows, безопасность, отладка

Как в Windows заблокировать список закрытых соединений через отладку? Скрин того что нужно заблокировать во вложении.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Извините, так Вы хотите отобразить список или заблокировать соединения? просто из вопроса непонятно

Comment: Заблокировать, статус соединения "Закрыто" но по факту активно

Comment: я думаю, Вам нужно сказать какую задачу Вы решаете, а не то, как Вы видите детали решения

Comment: Нужно заблокировать активное соединение которое маскируется под закрытое

Comment: а что это за приложение? как Вы решили, что это приложение, которое маскирует?

Comment: Ну как бэ на скрине видно невооруженным взглядом что это вирус

Comment: боюсь, что тут так просто Вам никто не ответит на этот вопрос, ещё и в такой формулировке.

Answer (score 0):

Вирус аппаратный, можно закрыть вопрос.